# What happens if a Non-Dragonborn wears the Amulet of Kings?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion, the-elder-scrolls-series

When I heard of the Amulet of Kings in Oblivion, I wanted to learn more about it. I found out only the one with the dragon blood, also known as the Dragonborn, can wear it as Baurus said just after Emperor Uriel Septim VII was killed by the Mythic Dawn. I wondered if I could equip the amulet. I did, and it says it slips off your neck. But if I, or any other non-Dragonborn, were able to wear it, what else will happen? Would it give you a curse? Would you have power, or not? I want to know what happens if someone who has no dragon blood were to wear the Amulet of Kings.

Comment: You answer your own question..

Comment: @Timelord64 okay so I edited it saying what else will happen besides making it slip of your neck.

Comment: Im doubtful there is ananswer other then "it can not be worn"

Comment: @Timelord64 we'll see about that.

Comment: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Amulet_of_Kings seems to indicate quite clearly that non-dragonborn cannot wear it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as within the game; nothing. The [Amulet of Kings](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Amulet_of_Kings) given to you at various points along the main quest line is just a 'regular' amulet with a script that checks if the player is trying to equip it. There are even ways to obtain versions of the amulet that lack the script that the player can equip.

Lore-wise; The [Amulet of Kings](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Amulet_of_Kings) is just an amulet that can't be worn by those who lack 'Dragon Blood' in their veins (the specific requirements have been debated). Presumably it reacts to them the same way it does the player in Oblivion, it just slips from their neck. It has no known negative effects and is largely used as a sword-in-the-stone type test.

Answer (score -3):

[According to the wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Amulet_of_Kings), the amulet only slips off someones neck. That is kind of weird, because I thought anything effective can happen to you, but it just slips off your neck. I understand now.